# How to pass variable (environment property) from CodeBuild to Beanstalk app in CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have a simple CodePipeline with three stages - source checkout, CodeBuild build docker image using `buildspec.yml` and producing `Dockerrun.json` artifact, and deploy to Beanstalk.

Now I want the application, which runs in the docker, to read a variable (environment property) set by CodeBuild stage during a build--a build number. How can I do that?

I have set `APPLICATION_BUILDNUMBER` variable in the `buildspec.yml` in `pre_build:commands` and listed it under `exported-variables`. It then appeared in AWS Console under CodeBuild *Build status* under Environment Variables tab under *Exported environment variables* with desired value.

Now how can I read it in my application running in docker in Beanstalk, which is a Spring Boot app (JAR)?
When I set the variable `APPLICATION_BUILDNUMBER` manually in Beanstalk > Configuration > Software >  Environment properties, I can read it easily. But I don't know, how to pass it from CodeBuild.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick look at the configuration properties of an Elastic Beanstalk action [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html#action-requirements), it cannot take an environment property from an external source.

A workaround can be to:

a. Set a SSM Parameter store variable from your CodeBuild action and then

b. Read the SSM parameter value in Elastic Beanstalk environment "hook" and export to the environment.

#### For a: Run this command from the CodeBuild buildspec:

```
$ aws ssm put-parameter --name "parameter-name" --type String --value "parameter-value"
```

#### For b:

You can deploy the hooks file in /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/ . Create the hook script via ebextension 'files' construct [2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-files). A minimal hook script to get the secret from SSM or Secrets Manager and exporting the secret to system, would look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

export MySecret=$(aws ssm get-parameters ---blah --blah......... )
```

It goes without saying that CodeBuild service role and EC2 Instance role (used with EB) needs to have the required permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:PutParameter",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:*",
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:*:*:*",
                "arn:aws:kms:*:*:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems quite complicated. What about passing docker run parameters in Dockerrun.json, which I'm generating in build stage?

Comment: Good idea but Dockerrun.json does not allow adding environment variables like a task definitio. You can possibly use commands argument: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html#single-container-docker-configuration.dockerrun

Comment: I turned out it's not possible to use the Command section in Dockerrun.json in my case. A docker image built by maven Spring Boot build-image has "/cnb/lifecycle/launcher" entrypoint. That command doesn't takes arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get the CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER environment variable from CodeBuild to ElasticBeanstalk so I could get the right release in Sentry.

The solution I ended up using was to update the ElasticBeanstalk environment variable from CodeBuild with aws-cli.

Make sure to leave enough time after this command so that ElasticBeanstalk isn't still updating when CodeBuild starts deploying your app, resulting in a failed deployment. Putting it in the pre_build section of your buildspec.yaml would probably help with that.

Here's an example:

```yaml
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - export BUILD_NUM=${CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER}
      - aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name YOUR-ENV --option-settings Namespace=aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment,OptionName=CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER,Value=$BUILD_NUM --region YOUR-REGION
```